# EC2 Instance creation fails due to VPC Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs, autoscaling, vpc

So I am following this link: [Autoscale based on SQS queue size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635241/autoscale-based-on-sqs-queue-size) to create an autoscaling group for my instances. I have read many articles about this problem that I am getting and many people are getting the same problem, but theirs occurs when they try to use "t1.micro". Whereas, I am using "c4.xlarge" instance type and I already have a VPC defined for my Image. Why am I still getting this error:

```
Launching a new EC2 instance. Status Reason: The specified instance
type can only be used in a VPC. A subnet ID or network interface ID is
required to carry out the request. Launching EC2 instance failed.
```

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: Please include more details about the steps you are following in creation of c4.xlarge instance.

Answer (score 2):

you need to include VPC information in your scripts or init:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/asg-in-vpc.html

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what sdk you are using, but with any sdk you have choosen, you need to specify the VPC subnets where you generate the instances.

When using aws cli to create a ASG, you specify the same using `--vpc-zone-identifier`

Please check the link to documentation below:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/create-auto-scaling-group.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are defining the subnet id in the cli command.
Although the service is different, aws cli generally follows the same syntax so adjust this to any resource.

```
aws emr create-cluster \
--name "Test cluster" \
--release-label emr-4.2.0 \
--applications Name=Hadoop Name=Hive Name=Pig \
--use-default-roles \
--ec2-attributes KeyName=myKey,SubnetId=subnet-77XXXX03 \
--instance-type m4.large \
--instance-count 3
```